# How do I store multiple values for a single item in a cell in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Is serialize the best way to do this?

If, say, I have a database of music and I want to classify music by genres.  If I allow for multiple genres for a given album, do I store them as an array and serialize them?  Like this?

`$array = serialize(array(1,2,3));` //  numbers are IDs of genres

I get that from another post here.  I know I can unserialize them.  What I don't get is how I would write an SQL statement that would retrieve some or all of the data.  What would my SQL statement look like if I wanted to retrieve all of the genres for a given album?

Comment: Or should I store my data another way, as I will have a long list of genres.

Comment: And what if I want to get just one of those values from the serialized array?

Comment: Very related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145255/storing-multiple-values-in-a-single-cell-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *really* want to normalise the data and store the genres and the album to genre association in different tables.

i.e.: You'd ideally have three tables:

1. **Albums** The album data
2. **Genres** The genre data
3. **Album -> Genre lookup** The album id and genre id that forms each association

By doing this you'll be able to trivially add/remove, etc. genres as required in the future and will be able to perform lookups by joining the tables rather than having to perform string manipulation.

Comment: Can I store multiple genres for an album doing this?

Comment: @shummel7845 Yes. You'd simply have two entries in the Album -> Genre lookup table for that album.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what queries you want to run, but you should put the genres into its own table:

```
Genre
id | name
```

and create a table that associates albums with genres:

```
Album_Genre
album_id | genre_id
```

Comment: +1 And the sql to pull the albums by genre is `SELECT * from Genre inner join Album_Genre on genre_id = id WHERE name = 'reagge'`

Answer (score 2):

You should normalize your database using an [association table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).

The Wikipedia article on [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups) has a good example involving people with multiple phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to model a many-to-many relationship (Music to Genre).  So, you should create a separate table (Genre) and then a cross-reference table (Music_Genre) that has the IDs from the Music and Genre tables.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

For a many to many relationship, you need a third table:

```
songs: id, name, ...

genres: id, name, ...

relation_songs_genres: song_id, genre_id
```