# SQL table structure

Tags: mysql

I posted a week or so about a database structure that I am trying to build.  I didn't quite get into the complexity of it, so that's why I'm reposting.  In the example, I used a CD collection as an example.

I understand that I need a lookup table for say my genres or publishers.  That's not a big deal to manage.

But there are eight lookup tables in this project and some of the tables have 150 entries in them. As I understand what was suggested, I need a separate entry for CD and its permutations of data.  So if I have say 20 entries on average in a lookup table, that's 20 x 20 x 20 x 20 x 20 x 20 x 20 x 20 permutations per CD.  Or am I misunderstanding?  How can I effectively create a master table to pull in all of the data without have a separate row for each permutation.  Do I need to write some more complex SQL to manage all of this?

Help!

Comment: Your cd table would have columns for `artist_id`, `genre_id`, `label_id` etc with foreign key relationships to the respective lookup tables. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: right i understand that.  But for say artist_id if there are 20 different artists, then I need 20 different entries.  Multiply this times eight tables and then you can begin to see my dilemma.  And then if there are 20 different publishers that don't correspond with artists, that's another 20.  See where this is headed?

Comment: Your artist table would have 20 artists, your genre table 20 genres. Why would you need to multiply these out to get every 400 permutations of artists and genres?

Comment: Because don't I need to have an artist_id to store in the master table to look up the value in the lookup table.  I have to store all those ids in the master table, don't I?

Comment: @shummel7845 - No. Were you advised that on SO? If so can you link to the question for context?

Comment: Don't I need a master table of some kind to store all the ids.  Let's say The Platters have six genres.  Then I need store each of the genre_ids for that in a master table right.  And then if there are seven publishers that don't at all correspond to the genres, I have to store all of that somehow.  Or is it the SQL that does all of the heavy lifting here?  Maybe that's what I'm missing.

Comment: The question was different, but here is the link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239320/how-do-i-store-multiple-values-for-a-single-item-in-a-cell-in-mysql  I don't know that it helps here.

Comment: OK, so what would an sql select statement look like to hook up these tables.  Sorry total newbie here.

Comment: Ah right that's talking about a many to many relationship. You wouldn't have **one** master table storing completely unrelated stuff though. It might be better if you give a concrete scenario in your question and ask how to structure it in the DB.

Comment: Whew!  OK, how do I manage that or structure things?

Comment: OK.  We have a materials spreadsheet that stores trade names of materials that can be altered with a laser.  Each trade name material has a category, fits into several subcategory, is used in several different industries, has a number of different applications, etc.  A user will come along and know their category, subcategory, industry and application. What I want returned is the trade name.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Are these totally independent? Are the sub categories constrained by the main category for example?

Comment: No.  They are all completely independent.

Comment: It sounds like I have some reading to do.  Can you recommend some good resources?

Comment: It looks like I need to do these joins to connect the tables.

Comment: But does that mean these is a unique SQL statement for each permutation?  Sorry to be so thick here.

Comment: @shummel7845 - I actually can't particularly (recommend some good resources) on this area. In your case above though you would have three different junction tables for all the many to many relationships you describe (`material_id, industry_id`), (`material_id, subcategory_id`), (`material_id, application_id`). As a particular material only has one `category_id` that would just go into the `materials` table.

Comment: OK, I think I got it.  Thanks for all your time, Martin.  It's much appreciated.  You saved us a lot of work.

Comment: @shummel7845 -- I added an answer I think might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Hogan.  It was indeed very helpful to have some concrete examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A brief overview of linking tables in SQL using the CD example.

Each disc can only have 1 label.  We create a table of labels that looks like this:

```
Label Table
```

```sql
LabelID     INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
LabelName   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

Then in the CD table we have the external reference to the Label

```
In CD Table
```

```sql
LabelID     INT(11) NOT NULL,
```

When we want to see the results we do a join... like this:

```sql
select *
from CD 
join Label on CD.LabelID = label.LabelID
```

---

One to many.

Lets say you have a one to many relationship then you need a joining table (I believe this is where you were getting confused.)

Fist we have the artist table for all artist available (note there can be more data in the artist table -- dob, home town... etc.

```
Artist Table
```

```sql
ArtistID     INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
ArtistName   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Then we create a joining table.  This will join one CD to many artists.  A CD can have one or more rows in this table representing each link to an artist on the CD.

```
CD2Artist Table
```

```sql
CDID    INT(11) NOT NULL,
ArtistID INT(11) NOT NULL
```

Of course we need an ID for the CD for this to work.
    In CD Table

```sql
CDID     INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
```

Then to select a list of artists for a particular CD you say

```
SELECT artist.artistname 
from cd2artist
join artist on cd2artist.artistID = artist.artistID
where CDID = <put cd id here>
```